# Mysql user-defined variable not updating when 0

Tags: mysql, innodb

for a data analysis project I need to split up a table concerning dated employee timesheets in the following format:

```
Employee|Start_Days|End_Days|...
0001|0|7|...
0001|7|14|...
0001|14|21|...
0002|0|7|...
0002|14|21|...
...
```

For the two columns I am using a user-defined variable @cur_Count in a CASE statement.

```
...
(
    CASE 
        e.EMPLOYEE
    WHEN
        @cur_Employee
    THEN
        @cur_Count := @cur_Count + 1
    ELSE
        @cur_Count := 1
        AND @cur_Employee   := e.EMPLOYEE
    END
) * 7 AS START_DAYS,
(@cur_Count + 1) * 7 AS END_DAYS,
...
FROM 
    tmp_MS_Relevant_Employees AS e, 
    hlp_MS_Calendar_Weeks AS c,
    (SELECT @cur_Employee = '', @cur_Count := 0) AS init
WHERE
    ...
```

This statement works perfectly fine - with the little exception that (since @cur_Count is reset to 1 in the ELSE clause) the first entry for an employee start with day 7 instead of 0.
However, if I use one of the following

```
@cur_Count := 0 
@cur_Count := @cur_Count * 0
@cur_Count := @cur_Count - @cur_Count
```

or reset the variable to 0 in any other way, the output looks like this:

```
Employee|Start_Days|End_Days|...
0001|0|7|...
0001|0|7|...
0001|0|7|...
```

So apparently the variable ignores any attempt to update its value once it is reset to 0. While this issue is easy to work around, it is still puzzling (and the workaround isn't tidy). Am I missing something here or is this a bug of MySql?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: where you initialize the variable. can you show the complete statement ? you can add a **CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cur_Count := 0) as init** to do that

Comment: @Bernd Buffen I added the initialization to the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the order of the `AND` expression to

```
    (@cur_Employee := e.EMPLOYEE)
    AND (@cur_Count := 0)
```

This is because `AND` performs short-circuiting. When you assign `0`, that's treated as `FALSE`, so it doesn't perform the assignment.

Another option would be to substract `7` after multiplying:

```
(
    CASE 
        e.EMPLOYEE
    WHEN
        @cur_Employee
    THEN
        @cur_Count := @cur_Count + 1
    ELSE
        (@cur_Count := 1)
        AND (@cur_Employee   := e.EMPLOYEE)
    END
) * 7 - 7 AS START_DAYS,
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that `:= 0` is treated as `FALSE`. That explains the issue. Unfortunately reversing the order in the `ELSE` clause doesn't solve it and at least right now I can't think of any other way to structure the query. The workaround you described is pretty much the solution I have been using so far. I guess I will have to stick with that for the moment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have been playing around with the `CASE` statement and have encountered some more strange behavior. With `ELSE @cur_Employee := e.EMPLOYEE AND @cur_Count := 1` the variable is also never updated. With `ELSE (@cur_Employee := e.EMPLOYEE AND @cur_Count := 1 AND @cur_Count := @cur_Count - 1` the variable alternates between values `0` and `1`, regardless of whether the `CASE` condition is met or not. Apparently there are some aspects of `CASE` that I don't fully understand (execution order?). The official documentation doesn't clarify this for me, do you know of any good sources on the topic?

Comment: The problem is that `AND` has higher precedence than `:=`, so it's treating it as `@cur_Employee := (e.employee AND (@cur_count := 0))`. I've added parentheses to override this.

Comment: Well, that worked. And it also explains some other oddities I have come across. Very useful to know, thanks!